# Expresión regular, método test()

Tags: javascript

Bueno agradecería si me pueden ayudar con un problema con la expresión regular al usar test(), me da true y false para la misma palabra como se muestra en la imagen. El tema es que no puedo sacar el global porque me estaría admitiendo en un input "lalala1234" (que no sería valido). ¿Cómo podría resetear test, algo así como decirle no recuerdes el input anterior?

Saludos

```
<script>

        //Function
        function validateForm(){
            let pattern = /^[a-z\u00f1À-ÿ]+(\s* [a-z\u00f1À-ÿ\r\n]+)*/gim;
            let name = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            let subject = document.getElementById('asunto').value;
            let msj = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;
    
            console.log(`name ${name} type ${typeof name}`)
            console.log(pattern.test(name));
    
            console.log(`subject ${subject} type ${typeof subject}`)
            console.log(pattern.test(subject));
    
            console.log(`msj ${msj} type ${typeof msj}`)
            console.log(pattern.test(msj));
    
    
        }
        //Main
        let form=document.getElementById('formulario');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            validateForm();
        });
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como el indicador `g` incrementa la posición del índice cada vez que encuentra el patrón y lo reinicia en caso contrario, entonces, si quieres forzar a qué empiece nuevamente de 0 luego de un `test`  tienes que  reiniciar valor del `lastIndex`:

```
pattern.lastIndex=0;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto ahora.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo podría resetear test, algo así como decirle no recuerdes el input anterior?

Eliminando el modificador "global":

```
let pattern = /^[a-z\u00f1À-ÿ]+(\s* [a-z\u00f1À-ÿ\r\n]+)*/im;
```

Si la expresión regular tiene el modificador global (`/g`), recordará la última posición donde encontró la coincidencia. Si no hay coincidencia (es decir, si la llamada a `test()` devolvió `false`), la posición (`lastIndex`) se reinicia a 0.

Documentación en inglés en MDN para [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag) y para [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)